# How to change dropdown arrow image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown navigation menu where I am using arrow up and down images for the dropdown links. What I want is that when I click on a  dropdown link means when I open the submenu, the arrow image should be the arrow-up image and when I close the submenu, it will go back to the arrow-down image. I have more than one dropdown link with the arrow images. The problem is that when I click on one of the dropdown links, the other link with an arrow image also gets triggered and changes. But I only want to change the image of one that I clicked. You can see and check the code below.

```js
const nav__items = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__items");
const nav__list = document.querySelector(".nav__list");

function toggleSubMenu() {
  if (this.classList.contains("nav__list--sub-active")) {

    this.classList.remove("nav__list--sub-active")

  } else if (nav__list.querySelector(".nav__list--sub-active")) {
    nav__list
      .querySelector(".nav__list--sub-active")
      .classList.remove("nav__list--sub-active");

    this.classList.add("nav__list--sub-active");

  } else {
    this.classList.add("nav__list--sub-active");


  }
}


function toggleArrowUpDown() {
  if (this.classList.contains("nav__list--sub-active")) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.arrow_down').forEach((arrow) => {
      arrow.src = "https://i.postimg.cc/Bb4ttXfk/arrow-up.png"
    })
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.arrow_down').forEach((arrow) => {
      arrow.src = "https://i.postimg.cc/Hn9ctbtT/arrow-down.png"
    })
  }

}

for (let item of nav__items) {
  if (item.querySelector(".nav__list--sub")) {
    item.addEventListener('click', toggleSubMenu, false);
    item.addEventListener('click', toggleArrowUpDown, false);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav__items {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.nav__list--sub {
  display: none;
}

.nav__list--sub-active .nav__list--sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav__list">
      <li class="nav__items">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__items has-submenu">
        <a tabindex="0">About <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hn9ctbtT/arrow-down.png" class="arrow_down" alt=""
          /></a>
        <ul class="nav__list--sub">
          <li class="nav__items--sub sub-item">
            <a href="#">Public Engagement
               </a>
            <ul class="nav__list--sub-sub">
              <li><a href="#">Cultural Map</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Culture</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Initiatives</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__items--sub"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          <li class="nav__items--sub">
            <a href="#">Publications</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__items has-submenu">
        <a tabindex="0">Programs & Initiatives <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hn9ctbtT/arrow-down.png" class="arrow_down" alt=""
          /></a>
        <ul class="nav__list--sub">
          <li class="nav__items--sub sub-item">
            <a href="#">Public Engagement
                </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__items--sub sub-item">
            <a href="#">Events
                </a>

          </li>
          <li class="nav__items--sub">
            <a href="#">Publications</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `document.querySelectorAll` in your `toggleArrowUpDown()` method, change that to `this.querySelectorAll` so you're only querying on `this` instead of the entire `document`.

But you can also take this one step further and use CSS classes to manage the display, so you only need to toggle the class.

```js
const nav__items = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__items");
const nav__list = document.querySelector(".nav__list");

function toggleSubMenu() {
  if (this.classList.contains("nav__list--sub-active")) {

    this.classList.remove("nav__list--sub-active")

  } else if (nav__list.querySelector(".nav__list--sub-active")) {
    nav__list
      .querySelector(".nav__list--sub-active")
      .classList.remove("nav__list--sub-active");

    this.classList.add("nav__list--sub-active");

  } else {
    this.classList.add("nav__list--sub-active");


  }
}


function toggleArrowUpDown() {
  let spanClasses = this.querySelector('span').classList;
  
  if (this.classList.contains("nav__list--sub-active")) {
    spanClasses.remove('arrow_down');
    spanClasses.add('arrow_up');
  } else {
    spanClasses.remove('arrow_up');
    spanClasses.add('arrow_down');
  }

}

for (let item of nav__items) {
  if (item.querySelector(".nav__list--sub")) {
    item.addEventListener('click', toggleSubMenu, false);
    item.addEventListener('click', toggleArrowUpDown, false);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav__items {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.nav__list--sub {
  display: none;
}

.nav__list--sub-active .nav__list--sub {
  display: block;
}

.arrow_down {
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/Hn9ctbtT/arrow-down.png');
  width: 12px;
  height: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.arrow_up {
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/Bb4ttXfk/arrow-up.png');
  width: 12px;
  height: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav__list">
      <li class="nav__items">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__items has-submenu">
        <a tabindex="0">About <span class="arrow_down" alt=""
          ></span></a>
        <ul class="nav__list--sub">
          <li class="nav__items--sub sub-item">
            <a href="#">Public Engagement
               </a>
            <ul class="nav__list--sub-sub">
              <li><a href="#">Cultural Map</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Culture</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Initiatives</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__items--sub"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          <li class="nav__items--sub">
            <a href="#">Publications</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__items has-submenu">
        <a tabindex="0">Programs & Initiatives <span class="arrow_down" alt=""
          ></span></a>
        <ul class="nav__list--sub">
          <li class="nav__items--sub sub-item">
            <a href="#">Public Engagement
                </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__items--sub sub-item">
            <a href="#">Events
                </a>

          </li>
          <li class="nav__items--sub">
            <a href="#">Publications</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: OMG, ITS WORKING!! Thank you so muchhh!! You saved my life. How come I could not think about that simple solution! I think I should practice more. Thanks again!